# React for web scraping. we will get many URL, but how I passed the CORS?

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping, proxy, web-crawler, cheerio

```
        
        //let firstTestURL = "https://blog.naver.com/mayoha/223015532241";
        //let testURLonProxy = "naver/siji5000/223015377877";

        let testURL = "https://peursen.tistory.com/270";
        
        axios.get(testURL)
        .then((response) =>{
            let body = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);

            let theURLtitle = $("title").text();
            console.log(theURLtitle);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
```

I am making web Scraping web program using React.
it have input for URL. if user put in the URL , the program will scraping to title and author.
but I face the problems Because of CORS.

so I searched, I wrote the proxy config for 'firstTestURL'.

but in fact that this program will meet a lot of URL with CORS.

so first, I wrote proxy config for few important URLs.
but this testURL is difficult.
in that case(that web platform) the words before fist dot is blog's name. and next is the blog platform.

I wanted make proxy config for that

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app){
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('tistory/', {
      target: 'tistory.com/',
      pathRewrite: {
        'tistory/^':''
      },
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  )

};
```

yes it didn't works.
how can I fix the config? or do you know about pass CORS ?

[image: the err console]

when I used just the test URL , I blocked CORS

[image]

And I tried proxy (I know.. it probably something wrong way to use)

Comment: If you're running on the client, you don't need Cheerio, which was created to port jQuery to the server. Are you making the request to your Express server as a proxy?

Comment: I solved from Proxy

Comment: Trying not free proxy server is work haha

Answer (score 0):

when I posted, I only used middleware proxy.
but I find out

outside proxy sever like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

yes, it only for dev. but it worked.
so I decided payed proxy server
(because I don't want handle own proxy server)